# Hive Udf exception

Tags: hive

I have a simple hive UDF:

```
package com.matthewrathbone.example;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Description;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;


@Description(
  name="SimpleUDFExample",
  value="returns 'hello x', where x is whatever you give it (STRING)",
  extended="SELECT simpleudfexample('world') from foo limit 1;"
  )
class SimpleUDFExample extends UDF {

  public Text evaluate(Text input) {
    if(input == null) return null;
    return new Text("Hello " + input.toString());
  }
}
```

When I am executing it using select query :
select helloUdf(method) from tests3atable limit 10;
method is the name of column  in tests3atable table.

I am getting below exception :
    FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: Line 1:7 Wrong arguments 'method':     Unable to instantiate UDF implementation class   com.matthewrathbone.example.SimpleUDFExample: java.lang.IllegalAccessException:   Class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDFBridge can not access a   member of class com.matthewrathbone.example.SimpleUDFExample with modifiers ""

Answer (score 4):

Declare the class as public, it should work

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. It turned out, eclipse was not refreshing the program which i modified. So please make sure that the modifications you make in your code gets reflected in the jar.